# Twitter Like Side Menu, Navigation Drawer or Sliding Menu - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

## [Twitter's Current Side Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILlwr.jpg)

> I want to have Twitter Like Navigation drawer aka Side Menu or Sliding 
>   Menu. I not willing to use any 3rd party library or cocoapod.

## [Uber's Side Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp3FP.jpg)

> And I have already created a Navigation drawer aka Side Menu or
>   Sliding Menu just like Uber have.

What Twitter had done is that they drag the view controller out of screen.
And in Uber they just bring out the Menu over the view controller

Comment: if you wan to use my custom slider view. here is link for that :- https://github.com/nisheeSheth/Custom_SliderView

Comment: you can use a brilliant `SWRevealViewController` swift version which can reduce your work.

Comment: I had tried that but it shows alot of alert

Comment: Hi @nishee, I love your library .. i have put an Issue on it on Github, kindly check and confirm if it is possible for you to add it. i f not kindly show me how to do it. thanks!

Comment: @nishee I basically want the the slider part darkened

Comment: Hello @CliveMakamara, i just give you ans of your issue. kindly check it.and more think you want to change color of slide view.?

Comment: Thanks @nishee. For the quick response

Comment: @Mr.Kanji can you share your uber side menu? :)

Comment: @nishee hi dear, your CustomSliderView.swift giving error says : -[UIView init] must be used from main thread only  code [    var viewToHideSlideMenu : UIView = UIView();
]

Comment: Hello @AliAlzahrani, I will check and update you soon.